# Replace Div with content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript/jquery and there is something fundamental that I am overlooking. I want to replace the content of a div with some text by calling a function. Absolutely every thing I have tried has failed.

http://jsfiddle.net/spuder/dTGBy/

html

```
<body>
<div id=test>

</div>
</body>
```

script

```
$(document).ready( function()  {

   getTest();

}



function getTest() {
    $("#test").html("Hello World");
    //$('#test').replaceWith('<h2>New heading</h2>');
    //$("#test").attr("text","http://www.w3schools.com/jquery");
    //$("#test").attr("href","http://www.w3schools.com/jquery");
    //$("#test").html("New text");
    //$(".test").html("New text");
    //$("test")html.("New text");
    //$("test").update("New text");
    //document.getElementById("testSpan").innerHTML = "42";
    // $("#test").html("<b>Hello world!</b>"); 
}

//This is supposed to be super easy ^

//http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_html_set
//http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_attr_set
//http://www.willmaster.com/library/web-development/replace-div-content.php
//http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/
```

Comment: there's a missing closing parentheses to finish your ready() call - have you looked in the console for Javascript errors?

Comment: why do you have two slashes before each line!!

Comment: The jsfiddle that you have linked to doesn't include the jQuery library, and you are using the $ expressions which require jQuery

Comment: check changes on  http://jsfiddle.net/dTGBy/3/

Comment: @rab, so its working now! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, the errors you made:

- Didn't include jQuery in JsFiddle
- Incorrectly ended your `document.ready`
- Forgot quotes around the div id

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   getTest();
});



function getTest() {
    $('#test').replaceWith('<h2>New heading</h2>');
    //$("#test").attr("text","http://www.w3schools.com/jquery");
    //$("#test").attr("href","http://www.w3schools.com/jquery");
    //$("#test").html("New text");
    //$(".test").html("New text");
    //$("test")html.("New text");
    //$("test").update("New text");
    //document.getElementById("testSpan").innerHTML = "42";
    // $("#test").html("<b>Hello world!</b>"); 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="test">

</div>
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ajp36/1/

Comment: fast, quick, and 100% accurate .. you deserve +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getTest();
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dTGBy/2/)